# DrawformattedText error in fuction TextBounds Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, display, psychtoolbox

I have an unsolved problem on my computer, my code work in other ones. Run the code without `DrawFormattedText` is ok (I displayed some picture in other parts of the code).

Here is the code to display the text:

```
Screen('Preference', 'SkipSyncTests', 0);   %I tryed this part with 0 or 1 but none of them work.
ScreenNumber=max(Screen('Screens'));
[w,wrect] = Screen('OpenWindow',ScreenNumber(end),[0 0 0]);%2400 x 1040
cycleRefresh=Screen('GetFlipInterval', w);
vbl=Screen(w, 'Flip');
[width, height]=Screen('WindowSize', w);
Screen('TextSize',w, 25); % SET TEXT SIZE HERE
Screen('TextFont', w, 'Times');
Screen('TextStyle', w, 1);
Textcolor=[255 255 255];
DrawFormattedText(w, 'Start experiment','center','center',Textcolor);
```

Here is the message error:

> win = 10
>
> Error in function TextBounds:     Usage error
>
> The external text renderer plugin failed to render the text string for
> some reason! % Very helpfull ^^
>
> Error using Screen Usage:
>
> [normBoundsRect, offsetBoundsRect, textHeight, xAdvance] =
> Screen('TextBounds', windowPtr, text [,x] [,y][,yPositionIsBaseline]
> [,swapTextDirection]);
>
> Error in DrawFormattedText (line 295)
> theight = RectHeight(Screen('TextBounds', win, tstring));
>
> Error in SCRIPT_PROSOC_CommentSerialObj (line 102)
> DrawFormattedText(w, 'Start experiment','center','center',Textcolor);